# git checkout <branchname> systematicaly modify files

Tags: git, git-checkout

This is driving me crazy and I can't find why it's doing this...

```
git clone git@github.com:/my/working/repo.git
--I don't do anything in the working copy--
git status
--no modification/no file to be commited--
git checkout another_branch
--I don't do anything in the working copy--
git status
modified: /some/file/that/I/touched.php
modified: /some/file/that/I/touched2.php
modified: /some/file/that/I/touched3.php
```

And when I do a git diff it shows only some line ending modifications.
I see you coming... You're gonna tell me that I have to set autocrlf to false... Already tried that, and changes nothing...

If anyone has an idea on how to fix this i'd be more than pleased...

Thank you.

Comment: One possibility: Case sensitive file system and the filenames in the other branch have different capitalization.

Comment: or you have bad autocrlf settings.

Comment: Is there a .gitattributes that does a smudge filter maybe?

Comment: What does `git diff` (or `git diff --staged` if the modified files are on the staging area) say?

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
git clone git@github.com:/my/working/repo.git
git branch another_branch
git checkout another_branch
git pull origin another_branch
```

I hope it should work for you.

Because if we do `git checkout another_branch` directly it will switch to the Remote branch not creating branch locally.

Second way is:

do `git checkout -b another_branch`